# fill javascript variable when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, onclick

For building pagination in combination with an api, when I press the *next* button, I want the value `next` to get assigned to a javascript variable so it can be sent to a PHP script. I have this so far but I am not very familiar with Javascript:

```
nextpage = document.getElementById('nextpage').onclick = document.getElementById('nextpage').value;

if(!nextpage==0){
    link =link+"&nextpage="+nextpage;
}
```

This way the Javascript variable gets posted into the url so the PHP script on the other hand can pick it up like this. For other variables I use:

```
mantinee = document.zoekform.mantinee.value;

if(!mantinee==0){
    link =link+"&mantinee="+mantinee;
}
```

If I do this, then it is directly posted to the url so the PHP script always thinks it needs to skip to the next page which isn't my intention. The buttons on its side calls `ajaxgetinfo()` when clicked.

**query.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['nextpage']))
{
  $nextpage = $_POST['nextpage'];
}
```

Here is all the javascript that gets every variable and passes them through. this is where the nextpage also needs to run

```
function vorige(){
sort = 'vorige';
ajaxGetInfo(sort);
}
```

function ajaxGetInfo(sort)
{
    var ajaxRequest;  // De variable wat Ajax mogelijk maakt

```
try{
    // Chrome, Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

link="query.php?";

datumreeks='';
if(document.zoekform.zo.checked==true){datumreeks="zondag";}
if(document.zoekform.ma.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"maandag-";}
if(document.zoekform.di.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"dinsdag-";}
if(document.zoekform.wo.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"woensdag-";}
if(document.zoekform.don.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"donderdag-";}
if(document.zoekform.vr.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"vrijdag-";}
if(document.zoekform.za.checked==true){datumreeks=datumreeks+"zaterdag-";}
link = link+"&datumreeks="+datumreeks;

datepicker = document.zoekform.datepicker.value;
if(!datepicker==0){link =link+"&datepicker="+datepicker;}

datepicker2 = document.zoekform.datepicker2.value;
if(!datepicker2==0){link =link+"&datepicker2="+datepicker2;}

zaal = document.zoekform.zaal.value;
if(!zaal==0){link =link+"&zaal="+zaal;}

genre = document.zoekform.genre.value;
if(!genre==0){link =link+"&genre="+genre;}

profiel = document.zoekform.profiel.value;
if(!profiel==0){link =link+"&profiel="+profiel;}

internationaal = document.zoekform.internationaal.value;
if(!internationaal==0){link =link+"&internationaal="+internationaal;}

prijslaag = document.zoekform.prijslaag.value;
if(!prijslaag==0){link =link+"&prijslaag="+prijslaag;}

prijshoog = document.zoekform.prijshoog.value;
if(!prijshoog==0){link =link+"&prijshoog="+prijshoog;}

mantinee = document.zoekform.mantinee.value;
if(!mantinee==0){link =link+"&mantinee="+mantinee;}

document.getElementById('nextpage').onclick = function(e){
  ajaxRequest.open("POST", link, true);
  if (nextpage) ajaxRequest.send("nextpage=yes");
}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", link, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = '<div align=center><i class="material-icons w3-spin w3-jumbo">refresh</i></br>Blijft dit staan? <a href="" onclick="ajaxGetInfo()">Klik hier.</a></div>';


ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that the Javascript variable (`nextpage`) remains empty until the button (`name="nextpage"` with `value="nextpage"`) is pressed? When it is pressed, the javascript variable `nextpage` should contain *"nextpage"*

Answer (score 2):

POST your variables instead of using GET:

```
document.getElementById('nextpage').onclick = function(e){

  ajaxRequest.open("POST", link, true);
  if (nextpage) ajaxRequest.send("nextpage=yes");
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = '<div align=center><i class="material-icons w3-spin w3-jumbo">refresh</i></br>Blijft dit staan? <a href="" onclick="ajaxGetInfo()">Klik hier.</a></div>';


  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but there will be no button to click on? and a submit refreshes the page. I builded the site with tabs so a refresh is not an option

Comment: also the value of nextpage should only be filled when pressed other wise it needs to have a different value which that will be is random because if the value is empty the script will not run

Comment: You said in your question that there would be a 'next' button? I don't understand your issue since you have edited the question.

Comment: well on index.php, where that js is, are multiple filters such as date ect. they are defined in the js above. with this js an API is called which limits on 100 records but leaves a link to the next 100 records which is defined on query.php. when button "nextpage" is clicked an if statement runs and parses the URL. 

So when the button gets pressed nextpage="yes" needs to be posted in the URL so query.php can pick it up and run the if statement

Comment: I see - in that case, instead of appending query variables to your url, you need to use post with your ajax request. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp - see POST request and put &nextpage=yes into the send function.

Comment: and that function needs to be in the current ajaxGetInfo() function? of how is it called by that specific button?

Comment: i've edited my script and implemented what's in your anwser but it wont work. when i check what the link containts with alert(link) it show that nextpage=yes is not added to the link. for the record link already contains other variables as shown in my original post.

Comment: Yes - it's not added to the link - it is sent as a post variable. This is the whole point!

Comment: ohwel youre right i was forgotten about that. ive edited query.php from isset(_GET) to _POST but when i press the button nothing happens

Comment: I can't help you if you don't post your updated code. If nothing is happening, first check your console for errors.

Comment: is now updated. errors are blocked by my company. but the innerhtml is not refreshing onclick of that button while other filter still refresh onchange

Comment: Put alert into your onclick function and check what values you are passing: alert(link+":"+nextpage);

Answer (score 0):

your problem is `nextpage = [...]` if i get your question right.

try it this way:

```
document.getElementById('nextpage').onclick = function(e){
    //do your request etc
}
```

here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nmLeetgu/

Comment: this almost does the trick exept for the fact that the page isnt loading anymore. i have posted the full javascript in the original post

Comment: i managed to get it posting to the link. but the innerhtml doesnt reload when the button is clicked for al other values it reloads exept this one